# Initializing network connection in Service

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement Service to manage network in my app. This service would be used to communicate with an external server from several activities.

How and when should I initialize connection to the server? I thought about doing this in service's onCreate method like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);

                ... 
            }
            catch(IOException e){
               // How to manage this exception?
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But if connection error would occur how could I tell that to a client (activity which calls this service) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using an IntentService instead of Service.

You can override onHandleIntent(Intent) and do your network job there becouse it doesn't run on the main thread.

Android Developers Docs

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only one request will be processed at a time.

To notify the activity about the Service response you can see a [great example here](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android#7-report-status-from-intentservice-to-activity)

Also I would consider [using an AsyncTaskLoader](http://www.concretepage.com/android/android-asynctaskloader-example-with-listview-and-baseadapter) if you are going to use it in multiple activities and you're expecting a response.